# New SE site for Programming Language Design!

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

As Solana is **the newest SE site**, many of you might remember the process that's in place for getting a new site approved, and many of you might remember how exciting it is to be one of the first users of a brand new SE site.

The [Programming Language Design](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation?referrer=NjE4NDEyZTRhYWI0MTA0NGZiMTI5MDZlZDhhMDk1MjE2OGM5Y2I2OGExYTQwNTFiNzAwZjc5OGEzZmE3OTQyOJyrV3dVI5xVz9VEVF0LfiP1mv6kDbcQB8iTVOM2FU-f0) proposal, which has begun with a ***very healthy start*** is one that I think a lot of people here might find interesting.

If you are excited about the launch of a new site, or curious to experience contributing to a brand new site, or otherwise have interest in participating in a new site about programming language design, I encourage you to [visit the proposal for Programming Language Design SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation?referrer=NjE4NDEyZTRhYWI0MTA0NGZiMTI5MDZlZDhhMDk1MjE2OGM5Y2I2OGExYTQwNTFiNzAwZjc5OGEzZmE3OTQyOJyrV3dVI5xVz9VEVF0LfiP1mv6kDbcQB8iTVOM2FU-f0) and to click on "commit"!  If you haven't ever done this before, make sure to click on "sign up" instead of "log in", but you won't have to do much more because Area51 will sign you up based on your existing SE credentials.